# nginx redirect mask

Tags: nginx, web-server, redirect

I'm new to nginx and am trying to figure out an issue with redirection. I'm trying to redirect a website from a host running a web application to another domain. That part I've done but I'm looking to mask it. When it redirects, I don't want the user to know they've gone to another domain.

I've substituted the domain names for privacy of my client. But, they are on a Linode at test.com that's running a web application that's at sub.test.com. All I want is for any user visiting test.com to be redirected to a temporary site hosted on other.com but without exposing the domain.

Previously, someone had shown me how to do it but it was a long time ago and I no longer have the information to reference. Can someone help me out? I don't want to expose the domain of the testing environment.

```
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  www.test.com test.com www.test.net test.net;

    rewrite ^ http://other.com/sub permanent;

    #location / {
    #    root     /srv/http/www.test.com;
    #    index    index.html;
    #}

}
```

Comment: So, you want to [proxy](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) it instead of redirecting?

Comment: That would work. I'm not sure the best way to do this really. I'm not very savvy with administration work as I am just taking over a project from someone else who used nginx.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to stick the destination site in a frame. But keep in mind that anyone with half a clue can figure out what the site actually is.

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle putting the destination site in a frame. Also, it's not that i'm worried about it for the sake of security, it's just for presentation purposes.